# How to remove html tag from json response?

Tags: php, json

Here's my code , i want to remove HTML tag from json respose

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE active=1 AND parentid = '$iddv'";
$db = $DB->query($sql);

while($rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($db)){
    $data[] = $rs2;
}

echo json_encode();
var_dump($data);
exit;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAT3U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well at first - why are you encoding your Tawk, and GA Scripts?

This doesn't make any clue.

If you want to encode the database result, you could just use:

```
while($rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($db)){
    $data[] = $rs2;
}

$encoders2 = json_encode($data);
var_dump($encoders2);
```

Please furthermore, expand your post, of what you want to do.